# Merge dataframes of different length at unique values (or count number occourrences) in R?

Tags: r, list, count, dataframe, histogram

In have carried out three experiments, each rusluting in a list of numbers.

```
data1 = c(1,1,1,2,2)
data2 = c(2,2,3,3,3,4)
data3 = c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4, 5, 6)
```

Now I want to count the occurences of each number in each of the experiments. I do this with `table`, since hist uses class mids (the nice thing about histo would be, that I can give it the list of unique values)

```
# save histograms
result = list()
result$values[[1]] = as.data.frame(table(data1), stringsAsFactors=F)
result$values[[2]] = as.data.frame(table(data2), stringsAsFactors=F)
result$values[[3]] = as.data.frame(table(data3), stringsAsFactors=F)

str(result)
```

Now I only have a list of dataframes of different length, But I'd like to have a single dataframe containinglists of the same length (I want to subtract them)

```
nerv=data.frame(names=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
nerv[[2]] = c(3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
nerv[[3]] = c(0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0)
nerv[[4]] = c(3, 0, 0, 6, 1, 1)
```

Is it somehow possible to tell `table()`, which values to count? Or is there another function that allows counter of a list of values in another list (`count unique(data1, data2, data3)` in data1)?

Or should I merge the data.frames and fill zeros into empty spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate the data frame:

```
lev <- unique(c(data1, data2, data3)) # the unique values

data.frame(names = lev,
           do.call(cbind,
                   lapply(list(data1, data2, data3),
                          function(x) table(factor(x, levels = lev)))))
```

The trick is to transform the numeric vectors to factors with specified levels. The function `table` uses all levels.

The output:

```
  names X1 X2 X3
1     1  3  0  3
2     2  2  2  0
3     3  0  3  0
4     4  0  1  6
5     5  0  0  1
6     6  0  0  1
```